# Append 2 Dataframes together only if a value from a column in df2 is in df1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, 1 that is has a list of emails and the second has a list of attachments. I want to create a single dataframe with emails and attachments, however, not all attachments have a corresponding email and these attachments should be excluded from the final dataframe.

Each attachment can be matched to its parent email using the a GROUPID which will match to the GROUPID of the email (as they are in the same document group). Example tables below:

Parent Emails Dataframe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMul9.png)

Attachments Dataframe[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEUEM.png)

Required Output Dataframe[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atpNj.png)

Please note from the above examples, two attachment with GROUPIDs DOC-000000011 and DOC-000000028 are not included in the final output as they do not have a corresponding parent email in the Parent Emails dataframe.

I have successfully written code to do this, however, it is hugely inefficient. First I compare each of the GROUPID's for each row in the 'attachments' dataframe against the 'parent_emails' dataframe. The result (true or false) is passed into a Series, which is then mapped back into the attachments dataframe into a new column 'Has Parent Email'. Then I merge the 'parent_emails' dataframe and the attachments dataframe(filter by 'Has Parent Email' == True). Code snippet below:

```
has_email = pd.Series({})
for index, row in attachments.iterrows():
    if (len(parent_emails[parent_emails['GROUPID'] 
                             == row['GROUPID']]) >0):
        has_email[index]=True
    else:
        has_email[index]=False

attachments.loc[:,'Has Parent Email'] = has_email

emails_attachments = parent_emails.append(
    attachments[attachments['Has Parent Email']==True])
```

This gives me the required result, but there has to be a more efficient way and I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that "Parent Emails Dataframe" and "Required Output Dataframe" do not show up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider retrieving a unique list of ids between both data frames via a `merge` then filter by lists with either `isin` or `query` and concatenate the two subsets:

```
shared_ids = pd.merge(emails, attachments, on='GROUPID')['GROUPID'].unique().tolist()

# CONCATENATE WITH LIST FILTERING (TWO EQUAL VERSIONS)
email_attachments = (pd.concat([emails[emails['GROUPID'].isin(shared_ids)],
                                attachments.query("GROUPID == @shared_ids")],
                               sort = False)
                      .reset_index(drop = True)
                    )
```

To demonstrate with data:

```
emails = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': [True, True],
                       'DOCID': ['DOC008', 'DOC023'],
                       'GROUPID': ['DOC008', 'DOC023'],
                       'FileName': ['epe model for 01/25/02', 'PLEASE READ'],
                       'FileType': ['Microsoft Outlook Note', 'Microsoft Outlook Note']})

attachments = pd. DataFrame({'EmailAttachment': ['Attachment']*4,
                             'DOCID': ['DOC008', 'DOC012', 'DOC024', 'DOC029'],
                             'GROUPID': ['DOC008', 'DOC011', 'DOC023', 'DOC028'],
                             'FileName': ['1-25act.xls', '1-29act.xls', 
                                          'Certification.doc', 'Certification.doc'],
                             'FileType': ['Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet', 'Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet',
                                          'Microsoft Word Document', 'Microsoft Word Document']})

shared_ids = pd.merge(emails, attachments, on='GROUPID')['GROUPID'].unique().tolist()

email_attachments = (pd.concat([emails[emails['GROUPID'].isin(shared_ids)],
                                attachments.query("GROUPID == @shared_ids")],
                               sort = False)
                      .reset_index(drop = True)
                    )

email_attachments
#   Parent   DOCID GROUPID                FileName                     FileType EmailAttachment
# 0   True  DOC008  DOC008  epe model for 01/25/02       Microsoft Outlook Note             NaN
# 1   True  DOC023  DOC023             PLEASE READ       Microsoft Outlook Note             NaN
# 2    NaN  DOC008  DOC008             1-25act.xls  Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet      Attachment
# 3    NaN  DOC024  DOC023       Certification.doc      Microsoft Word Document      Attachment
```

Comment: Thank for responding. Unfortunately this approach appears to be returning the full list of both dataframes.

Comment: Parfait, thank you for your help on this, it appears this has done the trick (still do some testing to confirm). I had to modify your code slightly to account for emails that dont have attachments as these needed to be included also, which simply meant modifying your merdge to: shared_ids = unique_top_level['BEGINGROUP'].unique().tolist(). Really appreciate you taking the time to put together such an informative response.

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, adjust accordingly. Didn't know all emails should be kept. Also, next time do not post such hard to read screenshots but embed runnable code (as I do here) to reproduce data. Happy coding and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the Pandas user guide to learn more about how to merge, join and concatenate dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

As a rule of thumb, you should not have to iterate over the rows of your dataframes to merge them together!

It is hard to help you without knowing how the dataframes that you are trying to append are organized, but if 'GROUPID' is the only column that "parent_emails" and "attachments" share in common, then you could go with `concat`:

`required_output = pd.concat([parent_emails, attachments], axis=1, join='inner')`

Setting join to inner will prevent rows containing GROUPID that have no equivalent in "parents_email" (*e.g.* DOC-000000011) from showing up in the concatenated dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this just seem to merge the two dataframes in their entirety.

Sorry S/O isn't allowing me add images.But effectively, my 2 dataframes all have the same columns,lets just take the key columns: DOCID|GROUPID

DocID is set as the index for both dataframes as its unique. The GROUPID is not unique, an email and all its attachments will have the same GROUPID. In addition, for the parent email, the DOCID == GROUPID

If I have a list of 5 emails, and a list of 20 attachments, only 5 attachments relate to the 5 emails, I just want to return a 2x2 dataframe with 10 entries.